# MVC4 AllowHtml not working with Dictionary<string, string>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I'm having this class in a C# MVC4 project:

```
public class SaveModel
{
    ....

    [AllowHtml]
    public string BodyHtml { get; set; }
    [AllowHtml]
    public Dictionary<string, string> AdditionalTemplate { get; set; }
}
```

An a controller actions looking something like this

```
public ActionResult SaveTemplate(SaveModel model)
{  
    ....
}
```

the BodyHtml is working fine but for some reason AllowHtml does not work on the Dictionary, and i'm getting an error like this:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from 
the client (additionalTemplate[0].value="<tr>..."
```

Is there any way to get get around it, except from disable validation for the entire request by putting [ValidateInput(false)] on my action?

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult SaveTemplate(SaveModel model)
{  
    ....
}
```

Comment: You didnt show what your view looks like, but you could use `@Html.Raw`.  This didnt seem worthy of posting as an *answer* but it prevents the view HTML encoding your string.

Comment: I'm also having this issue, haven't found a workaround yet.

Answer (score 2):

As fast workaround you can create your own type for key value collection where would be two properties. Value property could be marked as AllowHtml like:

```
    public List<MyCustomItem> AdditionalTemplate { get; set; }
```

blabla

```
class MyCustomItem
    {
      public string Key { get; set; }
      [AllowHtml]
      public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```